# TypeScript not generating declaration files

Tags: javascript, typescript

For whatever reason, I am not getting any .d.ts files. How can I produce definition files correctly?

## compile command

```
npx tsc
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "rootDirs": [
      "src",
      "stories",
      "config"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    // Ensure that .d.ts files are created by tsc, but not .js files
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    // Ensure that Babel can safely transpile files in the TypeScript project
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "docs"
  ]
}
```

## src

```
src/components
src/components/FormGenerator
src/components/Input
src/components/Link
src/components/List
src/components/MoneyFormat
src/components/Select
src/components/Svg
src/components/TemplateComponent
src/components/TemplateComponent/index.tsx
src/components/TemplateComponent/TemplateComponent.stories.js
src/components/TemplateComponent/TemplateComponent.test.tsx
src/components/TemplateComponent/TemplateComponent.tsx
src/components/Text
src/components/Text/index.tsx
src/components/Text/Text.stories.js
src/components/Text/Text.tsx
src/components/index.tsx
src/themes
src/themes/default
src/themes/default/fonts
src/themes/default/palette
src/themes/default/typography
src/themes/default/themeDefault.ts
src/themes/default/variables.ts
src/themes/fonts.d.ts
src/react-app-env.d.ts
src/setupTests.js
```

Comment: `"include": ["./src/**/*.tsx"],` that already removes any `.ts` or `.js`

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte So does that mean I should remove this line? Or include this line? I don't follow sorry!

Comment: How i understood it, `include` doesn't prevent non-included files from being added to a build (could still be imported), but doesn't add them from the start. If the dependencies between your files from your `import`s (types only here probably?) don't go from `.tsx` to all those files, they'd not get used. Why it produces absolutely zero declaration files, i don't know, but the line at least looks like it could be part of the problem - especially, if it was added without knowing, what it does. Tl;dr; it might be an issue, but i can't be sure removing it will solve everything.

Comment: I think, `baseUrl` messes things up. Usually, it's _the folder containing `src`_ , e.g.,  `"baseUrl": "./"`

Comment: Oh very interesting. Removing the `include` file has produced, inside of `/dist/src/components` all of the definition files...